# How to use SSL certificate for subdomains

Tags: ssl, certificate

We have a client CompanyX. The website is https://www.companyx.com and their IT guys got a SSL certificate for us.

This is only a single domain SSL certificate and it’s a yearly subscription.

We have subdomains on the domain that we want to add as well, for example : https://subdomain.companyx.com and this is under Let’ Encrypt for now and want to add it to the main SSL certificate.

From the IT guys :

> Can the stage and admin pages not be locally signed? If they are to be
> used by internal staff and those with access to the companyz.com (also
> have a SSL certificate) domain, then it should be possible to sign it
> internally.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> ... this is under Let’ Encrypt for now and want to add it to the main SSL certificate.

You can use a certificate only for the domains it was issued for. You cannot add domains to an existing certificate. If whoever you provided with the subscription based certificate needs to get a new certificate with all the domains - no idea if they are able and willing to do this.

Comment: Except if the certificate was issued for `*.example.com` as that will cover automatically all "subdomains". With  `example.com` added as well for apex.

Comment: Nope the ssl certificate was generate only on example.com and not *.example.com. I will ask them to update the ssl certificate. Thanks.